# Serial port - Cannot set Service center SMSC address - AT+CSCA? returns error, smsd returns initialization error

Tags: linux, serial-port, sms, gsm, at-command

I almost spent a week trying to configure a serial port in order to be able to use it for sending SMS. Let me explain my situation: I use a notebook with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the machine has an integrated GSM modem, the serial port is `/dev/ttyACM0`, here is some `wvdialconf` output:

```
$ sudo wvdialconf
...
ttyACM0<*1>: Modem Identifier: ATI -- Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CORPORATION
...
ttyACM0<*1>: Max speed is 460800; that should be safe.

Found an USB modem on /dev/ttyACM0.
Modem configuration written to /etc/wvdial.conf.
ttyACM0<Info>: Speed 460800; init "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2"
```

I have tried many different tools in order to be able to send an SMS:

- Tried this PHP script https://gonzalo123.com/2011/03/21/howto-sendread-smss-using-a-gsm-modem-at-commands-and-php/ (didn't work, the script hangs and I doesn't return any output);
- `smstools` and `smsd`, installed with `apt-get install smstools`: I try to put an SMS file into `/var/spool/sms/outgoing`:

  ```
  To: xxxxxxxxxxxx

  This is a test message.
  ```

  the SMS file is collected from `/var/spool/sms/outgoing` by the `smsd` daemon, but then the daemon places it into `/var/spool/sms/failed` and if I look at the file, I see:

  To: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  Modem: GSM1
  IMSI:
  Fail_reason: Modem initialization failed
  Failed: 16-07-03 17:10:03

  This is a test message.

  This is the section inside `/etc/smsd.conf` for the GSM1 device:

  [GSM1]
  init = "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2"
  device = /dev/ttyACM0
  incoming = yes
  pin = xxxx
  baudrate = 460800
  smsc = yyyyyyyyyyyy

  I also tried to specify the init command without the `"` quotes, still get the same error. I think the init command should be the one `wvdialconf` outputs me (see above), so why isn't it working?
- Also, I tried using `cu -l /dev/ttyACM0` and type raw AT commands, but I cannot set the SMSC address, cause when I type `AT+CSCA?` it outputs me `ERROR`:

  $ cu -l /dev/ttyACM0
  ...
  AT+CSCA?
  ERROR

  AT+CSCA="yyyyyyyyyyyy"
  ERROR

Can someone help me fix this issues I am facing? Did you experience the same errors as I?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more specific error responses than just `ERROR` by running

```
AT+CMEE=2
```

See chapter 9, *Mobile Termination errors* in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) for more details on the command and the error codes.

Comment: I have tried `AT+CMEE=2`, I get the following error: `+CME ERROR: SIM busy`, but I can't find what that means online.

Comment: What does that mean? That I should wait for some seconds? But I wait and type again and I stille get the same error...